# Add custom class to specific wp_nav_menu() ul

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there a way to apply a custom class to a WordPress menu `<ul>`? Is there an argument of the `'class' => 'my_class'` type?

I use

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'custom-menu' ) ); ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work, I think:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array('theme_location' =>'custom-menu',
'menu_class' =>'your-class')); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply but my question is for the <ul> element. This code adds the class to the <div>. Is there a way around it?

Comment: go through this [link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu).

Additionally you can use use jquery to add or change the class of any element.